# In behalf vs on behalf. Which one is used more?

Tags: word-choice

I'd like to know which one of the following is used more and is the corrected form in speaking.

- Could you go to the meeting **in behalf** of me?
- Could you go to the meeting **on behalf** of me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick online search finds an answer here: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/behalf. Quoting a note on this page (all emphasis added is mine):

> Usage Note: A traditional rule holds that `in behalf of` and `on behalf of` **have distinct meanings**. According to this rule, `in behalf of` means "for the benefit of," as in *"We raised money in behalf of the earthquake victims"*, while its counterpart `on behalf of` means "as the agent of, on the part of," as in *"The guardian signed the contract on behalf of the child"*. But as the two meanings are quite close, the phrases are often used interchangeably, even by reputable writers. Statistically, `on behalf of` is used **far more frequently** than `in behalf of`…

I would also add that "on behalf of me" sounds awkward; instead, "on my behalf" would sound a lot better. Second, in this particular phrase, using "on behalf of" seems out of place; instead you can say "instead of me" (in my opinion).